# Which is the complexity to build a BFS tree for a graph?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know that a BFS takes O(n+m) time where n are the nodes and m are the arcs.

What about building the tree while doing the BFS?

Does it adds another n as long as in the worse case the tree is completely unbalanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure I am following but if by:

> Does it adds another n

You mean the complexity will be `O(n+m+n)`, note that `O(n+m+n) = O(n+m)`, so there is not really issue here.

The building of the tree can be done in `O(n+m)`, since it can be represented as an array `a[1,...,n]` where `a[i] = j if and only if node i is connected to node j in the tree` (and special mark for root)

So, during the BFS, when node `v` "discovers" node `u`, you just need to do `a[u]=v`, this is done in constant time, and is done exactly `n` times, so the total complexity remains `O(n+m)`

Comment: You said that when node `v` discovers node `u` I've to add `a[v] = u`. Shouldn't it be the reverse? The same node can discover more nodes. Is it a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: One more question. And what if we want to build the tree as a 'tree' and not as an array? I mean, if I have a real tree structure I can determine how far the node is from the source looking at its depth. How expensive is in the worse case to build such a structure?

Comment: It's still the same. Simplest solution: building a tree from the array can be done in `O(n)`, thus building an during BFS and then building a tree is `O(n+m)`. More efficient approach will be to build it directly, but it is the same on terms of big-O notation.